# How to convert SQL query to Django query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-queryset

**Django model**

```
class Imones(models.Model): # Clients
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    pavadinimas = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45) # name

class Priekabos(models.Model): # Products
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sutarties_nr = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45) # contract_number
    vin = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45, verbose_name='VIN') # vehicle_identification_number
    imones = models.ForeignKey(Imones, models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Įmonė') # client_id


class Saskaitos(models.Model): # Invoices
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    apmoketa = models.BooleanField(default=0) # Paid in full
    imones = models.ForeignKey(Imones, models.DO_NOTHING) # client_id
```

**MySQL query:**

```
SELECT distinct sutarties_nr, vin, apmoketa 
FROM priekabos pr
LEFT OUTER JOIN saskaitos sa
ON pr.imones_id = sa.imones_id
WHERE apmoketa=0 or apmoketa is null
```

Could someone explain how to translate MySQL query to Django query? I've tried:

```
obj = Saskaitos.objects.filter(apmoketa=0)
queryset = Priekabos.objects.filter(imones__in=obj.values('imones')).values()
```

But it doesn't return all values as expected. One more question - how to make Imones.pavadinimas appear in queryset results instead of plain id? Now it looks [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1345j.png)